# Data structure for partitioning the integers from 0 to N into disjoint sets

Tags: data-structures

I require a data structure that partitions the integers from `0` to `N` into disjoint sets, like so:

```
{0, 1, 7},
{9},
{4, 5},
{6, 2, 8, 3}
```

With the following operations implemented efficiently (better than `O(N)`):

*Which set does an element belong to?*

```
0 -> [0], 8 -> [3]
```

*Iterate over all the members of a set*

```
[2] -> {4, 5}
```

*Move an element to a different set*

```
8 [3] -> [1]
```

*Merge two sets*

```
merge [0], [1]
```

*Move 1 or more elements to a new set*

```
[4] = new set {2, 4}
```

An obvious solution is something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sets;
std::vector<int> elementToSetIndex;
```

but that requires many heap allocations for the `vector<vector<int>>`.  I'd like to use fewer heap allocations if possible.

The number of elements `N` will be fixed for the lifetime of the structure.

Comment: You can't iterate over a set of any kind in less than `O(n)` by definition, and merger is probably similar since even with `O(1)` insertion inserting `n` elements is `O(n)`. You basically need good insertion and access times. Are the partitions always going to be contiguous like in your example?

Comment: Contiguous partitions can make things a lot faster. Requiring just adding/moving/removing a pointer for everything but iterating.

Comment: No, they are not contiguous.  Changing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I was taking an algorithms class that addresses this type of problem. It is solved using a data structure they call Union-Find:

Recommended read : https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf
Comes complete with java implementations of the UF ADT

Read even more: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/

Comment: The union-find structure doesn't support iterating over all the elements of a single set efficiently.

Comment: @japreiss, it actually does support iteration, but the iteration is not efficient i.e. not O(N). However it is doable and here is [python code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3YhWUWL5lcgOG9XcU8tTDRiZVU/edit?usp=sharing) that shows what the iteration could look like

Comment: I couldn't recall the name and thus couldn't look it up and hence made something, but my approach implements UnionFind with path compression as a undirected graph, which provides a path from the integers to the root and from the root to the integers. The python code is basically a directed graph. Although, I'm fairly sure it's still slightly worst than O(N) of iterating. Although, as mentioned in my answer, on average it should be O(N).

Comment: Also iterating is technically O(M) where M is the size of the subset. The total size of the subsets will be O(N). So iterating can be less than O(N) if there are enough subsets, say sqrt(N) or so.

Answer (score 0):

If for the merge operation you guarantee that the values on one part of the merge all lower than the values on the other side of the merge you can do all operations on log(N) except listing the element (which is log(N) + the_number_of_elements). Example:

Merging {2, 5, 7} with {9, 10, 11} => {2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11}
But Not: {2, 5, 7} with {4, 6}.

If this is what you want you could use a Treap: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap

Later Edit: You can implement the treap solution for the general merge case
I'll try explaining the solution assuming you have some general knowledge of Treaps

So here's how it works:

- each element should represent a Treap Node. It should hold a pointer to his father and the two sons, the value itself, the randomly generated priority and the number of nodes in the subtree.
- The key of the node won't be the value (as you would expect) but the index of the node in the inorder traversal of the tree (which can be calculated in O(log n) because of our structure)
- Operation 1 : To find the treap that holds the information just go up on the treap until you reach a node that doesn't represent a value, but an entire treap (you could have a boolean field, or any other way you like). O(log n)
- Operation 2 : Just do an inorder traversal of the that specific treap, you're done (it is O(number of elements) )
- Operation 3 : Remove the node (like usual in a Treap) and insert it the specific Treap at the end (its key would be greater than the key of any other element in that Treap so it's easy). Both operations take O(log n)
- Operation 4 : This one is actually pretty easy. You merge the two treaps (with the typical merge treap algorithm) with the convention that any element on the right compares greater than every element on the left (because after the emrge every element on the right wil have a higher index in the inorder traversal than any element on the left). You're choice of who's left and who's right, it doesn't matter. Complexity: O(log N).

  - I suspect here that by merging you mean moving everythimg from one set to the other, leaving the first one empty
- Operation 5 : Move some elements to a new set. This is equivalent to

  - Creating a new set: Just create a new treap root O(1)
  - Move every element with operation 3: O(log n) per element

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make the merge operation O(1) and provide amortized O(1) run-time for most of the other operations. Although, repeated merge operations can slow it down to O(M) where M is the number of merges that have been done. This is done by a lazy evaluation with a tree with no limit as to how many child nodes each node has.

The best way is to use an undirected forest graph. Where every set becomes a tree, which I'll refer to as a tree-set for clarity. Unlike most implementations of a tree-set this tree will not be a binary tree. Each node in the tree-set contains three types of links. There is a single node-supernode link if the node is not the root of the tree-set. There are also any number of node-subnode (child) links as well as any number of node-integer links. It should be made so that integers/subnodes/supernodes can be added/removed at O(1) cost for each removal. Supernodes are used to allow traversal towards the root rather than just away from it.

The operations go as followed, with nodes being labeled as letters in the examples.

- Which set does an element belong to?: Look up the element in the graph and go up the treeset until the root is reached keeping track of the nodes accessed along the way. Cut the links between the nodes and make it so that the element and each node directly links to the super node. For example, if the path followed was [1,A,B,C,Z], with Z being the root node of the tree-set. Then the undirected edges (1,A), (A,B), and (B,C) would be removed and replaced with edges (1,Z), (A,Z), and (B,Z) with the direct link to the root node being ignored to avoid removing it then adding it back.
- Iterate over all the members of a set: Recursively iterate over all of the integers by following subnodes. Since this iterates over all of the integers, all of the edges (regardless of type) in the tree-set can be deleted and every integer can be made to have a direct node-integer connection with the root node.
- Move an element to a different set: Look up the element in graph. Delete it's current node-integer edge and replace it with a direct node-integer edge with the root of it's new tree-set.
- Merge two sets: Each root node should keep track of the depth of the tree-set. This is used to decide which root node of tree-sets to be merged will become the root node of the merged tree-sets. The idea during a merge of k tree-sets is to make all of the root nodes of the other tree-sets direct subnodes of the root node of the tree-set with the greatest depth. This results in the new depth being the same as the max depth or the max depth plus one if there are two or more max depth tree-sets. Therefor merging tree-sets of the same depth leads can lead to having to multiply every operation cost by O(log M). The benefit is that the log is actually at least 2 rather than exactly 2 since the tree-sets are not strictly binary.
- Move 1 or more elements to a new set: Create a new root note then use that as the different set and run "Move an element to a different set", for each element to be moved. Amortized O(k) where k the number of elements to be moved.
- Copying tree-sets can be supported by allowing multiple node-supernodes links and treeing the roots at the end of each of those supernode chains separately. This approach allows for a lazy copy where the copying is done over time rather than right away. For simplicity though, it's easier to just use one super-node for every node.

Edit: I'd thought I recalled seeing this approach before. This is UnionFind with path compression implemented as a undirected graph.